# Django forward www.domain.com to domain.com with fastcgi RewriteRule

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, fastcgi

I want to forward `www.myapp.com` to `myapp.com`.

My current htaccess

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine on
# Set up static content redirect:
RewriteRule static/(.+)$ myapp-folder/public/static/$1
# The following two lines are for FastCGI:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I tried adding below lines to above content

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myapp.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://myapp.com/ [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't give me the output I want. Without fastcgi I can just replace those lines since my app depends on it how can I add this forwarding without removing fcgi rule.

Comment: Add the new lines before the others (after `RewriteEngine on`)

Comment: @Croises post it as answer so I can accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first redirect:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
RewriteEngine on

# www.myapp.com to -> myapp.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://myapp.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

# Set up static content redirect:
RewriteRule static/(.+)$ myapp-folder/public/static/$1
# The following two lines are for FastCGI:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ application.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```